# How to upload SQL Server 2012 database tables along with data to google big query?

Tags: sql-server-2012

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/third-party-tools

How to upload SQL Server 2012 database tables along with data to google big query???

Answer (score -3):

1. Right Click on database -> Tasks - >Generate Script.
2. Select Specific data object -> select name of you table
3. Next -> Advance Options
4. In Type of data to script, select "Schema and Data"

This process is of Sql server 2008, hope it is same of 2012 also.

Comment: This is not compatible with BigQuery